# W: Failed to fetch http//us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources 404 Not Found

Tags: proxy

i am new in ubuntu. i just install ubuntu server 9.04(old because my server only support this version).setup is complete .ip set perfectly i can ssh from other computer so ip setup is good. but i cant assess internet. when i put

=====apt-get update======

W: Failed to fetch http//us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/multiverse/source/Sources 404 Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead. .i guess in proxy there some problem happen. i donot have any user or password for proxy my proxy adress is 172.22.0.2:8080

i did this

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@172.22.0.2:8080
```

but no luck. i did changes in vi /etc/bash.bashrc adding

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@172.22.0.2:8080/
```

but no luck can you help me.how can i set my internet works .

Comment: @charlesbridge Indeed, good find. I would still have to urge the OP to find a supported distro. The Jaunty stuff in old-releases does not get new security updates.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 9.04 is not supported anymore, so no more updates for it.

Try upgrading to 10.04LTS* (which has a 5 year support, untill 2015), or Ubuntu 12.04LTS (until 2017).

*LTS=Long term support version, every two years

Comment: thanks for your reply but how can chk my internet is working? my server is IBM x series 235.does that support 10.4 lts ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: i tried but harddisk not fount in 10.10 or 12.04